# Ruby and Cucumber : warning: class variable access from toplevel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I spend around 4 - 5 hours on this and now seeking help from you. I am trying to execute a Cucumber feature file via Ruby and getting below error via command prompt.

```
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansic
on/) to get coloured output on Windows
D, [23-10-2014 09:19:09 #1244] DEBUG -- : --------------------------------------
--
D, [23-10-2014 09:19:09 #1244] DEBUG -- : start time:  2014-10-23 09:19:09 +1100

C:/testapp/features/support/env.rb:56: warning: class variable access from toplevel


Variable is set in env.rb file and feature file and ruby code as below

Given(/^Testing feature"(.*?)" Open the page$/) do |feature_name|

  test_url = $url_config["testdata"]["test_poc"]["test_url"]
  @browser = $browser_instance
  @browser.goto(test_url)
  $logger.debug "Opened the page"
  puts "Opened the page"
end
```

Note: When I put the URL directly to the test_url = "http://www.google.com" it's working.

Comment: Are you using `Capybara`?

Comment: Can you please post your env.rb where the variable is set?